# magento is not updating and edited category

Tags: php, magento

I have tried to update my category in magento version 1.9.3.2 in the last coupe of day. I changed the heading, the picture and text in the category for weddings. I saved it, nothing happened. I then cleared browsers, cookies, and refreshed my hosting, still nothing. I just don't know what else to do? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you cleared Magento Cache?

Comment: Thank you, I have just flushed all the cache in the control panel which said cache. Tried a different browsers and still the same as it was before the change.

Comment: In case someone else has the same problem with not being able to change the category pictures and text. 
The issue was that I have 3 stores and needed to click the store view pertains to the store and category I wanted to edit. What I did was just click the category in of the store I wanted while all three were showing.